# Only Display Thumbnail if Larger Than

Tags: post-thumbnails

Is there a way to only display `<?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ); ?>` if it is larger/smaller than specified dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to make this work with a filter on `post_thumbnail_html`.

```
function filter_thumb_html($html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr ) {
  $dimensions = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id, $size);
  if ($dimensions[1] > 500 || $dimensions[2] > 500) {
    return '';
  }
}
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html','filter_thumb_html',1,5);
```

I am not sure what you mean by "if it is larger/smaller...". I don't know if need both conditions at once, or one or the other, or if you need to change the restrictions dynamically. The code above should give you a working model though.

### Reference

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php#L85

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$width = 200;
$height = 200;

$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) );

if($image[1] >= $width && $image[2] >= $height ){
    the_post_thumbnail($size, $attr);
}
```

Define `width` and `height`, and the `size` and `attr` that you want.

Comment: This did not work for me.